# Error en la sentencia if

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación donde hay dos tipos de usuarios (manager y técnico), cuando un usuario se logea depende del tipo que sea le aparecerá un menú u otro, cuando el usuario esta logeado cuando hace click en el header quiero que le lleve a su menú correspondiente.

En la sentencia if que pongo a continuación no me hace el if bien, salta al else siempre, ya este en un usuario manager o en un usuario técnico.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['numero_empleado'])) {

  header('Location: Login');

}

require 'conexion.php';

    $records = $conexion->prepare('SELECT numero_empleado, email, cargo, password FROM usuarios WHERE email=:email');

    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $resultados = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $_SESSION['numero_empleado'] = $resultados['numero_empleado'];

        if ($resultados['cargo'] === 'manager') {
            header('Location: ../Menus/menu_manager.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: ../Menus/menu_tecnico.php');
        }
?>
```

Perdón por la forma de poner el código, pero soy nuevo y todavía no se como poner las cosas.

CÓDIGO LOGIN

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['numero_empleado'])) {

  header('Location: Login');

}

require 'conexion.php';

if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){

    $records = $conexion->prepare('SELECT numero_empleado, email, cargo, password FROM usuarios WHERE email=:email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $resultados = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';

    if (count($resultados) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $resultados['password'])){

        $_SESSION['numero_empleado'] = $resultados['numero_empleado'];

        if ($resultados['cargo'] === 'manager') {
            header('Location: ../Menus/menu_manager.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: ../Menus/menu_tecnico.php');
        }

    }else {
        $message = 'La contraseña es incorrecta';
    }

}
?>
```

Login

```
<?php require 'partials/header.php'; ?> 


    <h1>Login</h1>

    <span> o <a href="registrarse.php">Registrarse</a></span>

    <?php if (!empty($message)): ?>
    <p><?=$message?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Pon tu correo">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingresa una contraseña">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78871/discussion-on-question-by-enrique-salazar-error-en-la-sentencia-if).

Comment: Si dices que no hace caso al código anterior al else debes revisar la condición que expones en en if. Ahí estará el problema, ya que si algo de esa condición no se cumple se va al else. Siento no poder ayudarte más :(
Una ultima cosa, si el primer bloque de código que has puesto es incorrecto, que no estoy seguro deberías borrarlo.

Comment: Claro, el problema es que no se que falla del código, porque la sentencia es la misma en el LOGIN y si funciona.

El código de arriba esta bien, la primera parte es del problema y la segunda parte es del Login que si me funciona que lo han pedido

Comment: El Login te funciona porque si estas usando el formulario. En el otro caso tendrias que usar sesiones no `$_POST`

Comment: Depura la variable para ver qué datos trae, si no viene con espacios en blanco, con caracteres extraños, si no es nula,.etc. Para depurar: `var_dump($resultados['cargo']);`

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\AppTrabajoColaborativo\Login\redirecionheader.php:18:null

Comment: Acabo de ver el debate en el chat. Lo primero que debes aclararte es sobre la forma en que el código va a recibir el email que usarás como criterio en la consulta, si es desde el formulario o de dónde. Usa `var_dump` para depurar todas tus variables, siempre te ayudará a saber lo que está fallando o está llegando vacío, nulo o con datos equivocados.

Comment: A que te refieres con sesiones no POST?

Comment: A que vas a necesitar usar sesiones en vez de $_POST

Comment: @A.Cedano el problema que tiene es que usa `$_POST` despues de pinchar en un link. No esta usando sesiones.

Comment: @JDev lo que se envía por un link se puede recuperar por POST o por GET. ¿Por qué dices que debe usar sesiones?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si lees bien su enunciado (que está fatalmente explicado) lo que quiere es que estando el usuario logueado si hace clic en el enlace para ir al home, le lleve a diferentes homes dependiendo del usuario logueado..